# Is the Pixel 5 really EOL in october?

Tags: security, updates, google-pixel, google-pixel-5

Iam using the Pixel 5 with original OS and currently on Android 13.

Reading here: https://endoflife.date/pixel the phone will not receive any further security updates from october on.

But Android 13 will still be supported, so is my phone really outdated and possibly unsecure from then on?

Comment: EOL really means software and security updates. Only newer Google phones get up to 5 years security updates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

This information is also available on [Google's support page](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4457705?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpixel-xl-a-a-g-a-g).

[image]

Your question focuses on the definitions of two things:

`Android Version Updates` : these are the updates to new numbered versions of Android, such as Android 13 you described, that usually include things like new features and design changes.

`Security Updates` : these updates are distributed on a monthly basis and are meant to provide critical improvements needed to keep the operating system secure.

You **can continue to use your phone** without either of these updates, but as you specified, your phone may be considered "less secure" than others with more recent updates. In practice, however, many people use devices for long periods of time after they're out of security update support life. In this case, the responsibility for security is yours, rather than Google's.